# perfect forwarding only via template

Tags: templates, forwarding

I was reading about "perfect forwarding".
Why does this only work with a template:

```
// example from justsoftwaresolutions  
void g(X&& t); // 2  
void g(X& t);  // 1  

template<typename T>    
void f(T&& t)  
{  
    g(std::forward<T>(t));   
}    


int main()  
{  
    X x;  
    f(x);   // 1  
    f(X()); // 2  
}
```

What is function is generated from the template for f(x) and f(X()) ?

What does std:forward

Answer (score 0):

Please read [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257144/when-to-use-stdforward-to-forward-arguments) to understand how `std::forward` works.

Regarding your question about "Why does this only work for template". My understanding is `std::forward` works for both template and non-template functions. But it is not necessary to use `std::forward` in non-template function. For example

```
void f(X&& x)
{
    g(std::move(x));
}
```

In the code above, we are **sure** that `x` is rvalue reference. so we use `std::move(x)` to "relay" the rvalue reference to function `g(X&& x)`. Of course, you can use `g(std::forward(x))` to do that as well, but I think it is not likely better than `std::move`.