# why is rhs.m_inner an lvalue and not an rvalue?

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013, move-semantics

```
class outer
{
  class inner
  {
  public:
    inner() { }
    inner(inner&& rhs);
  }
public:
  outer() { }
  outer(outer&& rhs)
   : m_inner(rhs.m_inner)  // why is rhs.m_inner an lvalue and not an rvalue?
  { }
private:
  inner m_inner;
};
```

Why is `rhs.m_inner` an `lvalue` in this context?  If `rhs` is an `rvalue`, why is `rhs.m_inner` not also an `rvalue`?

Comment: There seem to be two separate questions here. The first is "Why is the move constructor not used unless I type `std::move`?". The second is "Why does my class have a copy constructor?". They are separate questions, not really related, and it would probably be better if you could edit your question to focus on only one of them.

Comment: For your first question: [in C++11 why use std::move when you have &&](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14486367)

Comment: For your second question it's already answered at [What are all the member-functions created by compiler for a class? Does that happen all the time?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3734247) basically having a copy constructor disables the implicit move constructor but not the other way around.

Comment: Okay, yes, that link does explain the answer.  This could be closed as yet-another-duplicate :)

Comment: @Mordachai it's one of the most confusing topics relating to `move`. That said the awesome [What is move semantics?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11540204) answers it perfectly under the section `Moving into members`. As awesome as the question is it's horrible at the same time again since it should probably be split up, it's too comprehensive and you can easily overlook the specific part you're looking for. Over and out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source text `rhs` refers to two different things here:

- The *variable* `rhs`, an rvalue-reference to an `outer` object. This variable has type `outer&&`.
- The *expression* `rhs` that evaluates the value of that variable. This expression has type `outer` and value category `lvalue`.

The lvalue/rvalue-ness of a reference variable determines to which value categories of expressions the reference can bind, it has no affect on the value category of expressions that evaluate the variable. Evaluating a reference always results in an lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

If `rhs` was an rvalue, then `rhs.m_inner` would be an rvalue too. However, `rhs` is a named variable (doesn't matter that it's an rvalue reference), so it's an `lvalue`.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [C++ Annotations](http://cppannotations.sourceforge.net/), to call `outer(outer&& rhs)`, one would use the code:

```
outer out((outer)outer()/*0*/)/*1*/;
```

Which at 0 constructs an *anonymous* object of type outer, and at 1 it constructs an object of type outer *with the name out*. (The `(outer)` is there to prevent `out` form being an `outer(outer (*)())`)

See the *anonymous* there? Now consider the definition of outer(outer&& rhs):

```cpp
outer(outer && rhs) : m_inner(rhs.m_inner) {}
```

`outer(outer &&)` has 1 argument of type `outer &&` *named rhs*.
Now, there is a perceivable difference between the statement 0 in ex. 1 and the first parameter: the former doesn't have a name, the latter does, hence removing the *anonimity* of the object. Now since the object has a *name* it is just a lvalue reference (which allows people to use a construct-by-swap idiom). 
 The problem arises, though, when someone needs to use it as a rvalue reference. For that the

```cpp
template<class T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move(T&& t);
```

function was created. What's it do? It ["obtains an rvalue reference to its argument and converts it to an xvalue"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) (more on all sorts of values [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)), which is exactly what we need! So, the final code could be:

```cpp
#include <utility>

class outer {
  class inner {
    public:
      inner() {}
      inner(inner && rhs) {}
  };

  public:
    outer() {}
    outer(outer && rhs) : m_inner(std::move(rhs.m_inner)) {}

  private:
    inner m_inner;
};
```

Note the `#include <utility>` and `std::move()` call.