# Move and Forward cases use

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, move-semantics

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html) to start to understand the move semantics and rvalue references in C++11.
At some point, he implements these two classes with the `std::move` in the move constructors explaining that

> we pass the temporary to a move constructor, and it takes on new life
>   in the new scope. In the context where the rvalue expression was
>   evaluated, the temporary object really is over and done with. But in
>   our constructor, the object has a name; it will be alive for the
>   entire duration of our function. In other words, we might use the
>   variable other more than once in the function, and the temporary
>   object has a defined location that truly persists for the entire
>   function. It's an lvalue in the true sense of the term locator value

```
class MetaData
{
public:
    MetaData(int size, const string& name)
        : _name(name)
        , _size(size)
    {}

    MetaData(const MetaData& other)
        : _name(other._name)
        , _size(other._size)
    {
        cout << "MetaData -- Copy Constructor" << endl;
    }

    MetaData(MetaData&& other)
        : _name(move(other._name))
        , _size(other._size)
    {
        cout << "MetaData -- Move Constructor" << endl;
    }

  ~MetaData()
  {
    _name.clear();
  }

    string getName() const { return _name; }
    int getSize() const { return _size; }

private:
    string _name;
    int _size;
};

class ArrayWrapper
{
public:
    ArrayWrapper()
        : _p_vals(new int[64])
        , _metadata(64, "ArrayWrapper")
    {}

    ArrayWrapper(int n)
        : _p_vals(new int[n])
        , _metadata(n, "ArrayWrapper")
    {}

    ArrayWrapper(ArrayWrapper&& other)
        : _p_vals(other._p_vals)
        , _metadata(move(other._metadata))
    {
        cout << "ArrayWrapper -- Move Constructor" << endl;
        other._p_vals = nullptr;
    }

    ArrayWrapper(const ArrayWrapper& other)
        : _p_vals(new int[other._metadata.getSize()])
        , _metadata(other._metadata)
    {
        cout << "ArrayWrapper -- Copy Constructor" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < _metadata.getSize(); ++i)
            _p_vals[i] = other._p_vals[i];
    }

    ~ArrayWrapper()
    {
        delete[] _p_vals;
    }

    int* getVals() const { return _p_vals; }
    MetaData getMeta() const { return _metadata; }

private:
    int* _p_vals;
    MetaData _metadata;
};
```

In the ArrayWrapper move constructor I tried to change `std::move` with `std::forward<MetaData>` and the code shows that if I call the ArrayWrapper move constructor this will call the MetaData move constructor, like the example with the `std::move`.

Of course if I don't use either `std::move` or `std::forward` the MetaData copy costructor will be called.

The question is, in this case, is there a difference between using `std::move` and `std::forward`? Why should I use one instead of the other?

Comment: "locator value"? Seriously?

Comment: Anyway, use `forward` when you want to forward. `move` when you want to (unconditionally) move.

Comment: What do you mean with "locator value"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a difference between using std::move and std::forward? Why should I use one instead of the other?

Yes, `std::move` returns an rvalue reference of its parameter, while `std::forward` just forwards the parameter preserving its value category.

Use `move` when you clearly want to convert something to an rvalue. Use `forward` when you don't know what you've (may be an lvalue or an rvalue) and want to perfectly forward it (preserving its l or r valueness) to something. [Can I typically/always use std::forward instead of std::move?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13219484/183120) is a question you might be interested in here.

In the below snippet, `bar` would get exactly what the caller of `foo` had passed, including its value category preserved:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T&& t) {
    bar(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

Don't let `T&&` fool you here - [`t` is not an rvalue reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14486367/183120). When it appears in a type-deducing context, `T&&` acquires a special meaning. When `foo` is instantiated, `T` depends on whether the argument passed is an lvalue or an rvalue. If it's an lvalue of type `U`, `T` is deduced to `U&`. If it's an rvalue, `T` is deduced to `U`. See [this excellent article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c/) for details. You need to understand about [value categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) and [reference collapsing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) to understand things better in this front.

Comment: Ok, so if I understood this right, the `std::forward` is almost always used with a Universal Reference to "forward" the type of the variable to a function which is "interested" to know what kind of value category is the variable. Right?

Comment: And, is there a way to print the value category of a variable?

Comment: @Agostino a value category is not a property of variables/objects etc., but a property of expressions

Comment: Yes, sorry, I got confused.

Comment: @Agostino `forward` is to forward the variable, not its type, retaining the original valueness of it. If it's a variable it's almost always an lvalue, even the result of `std::move` when assigned to a variable becomes an lvalue; see [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc8393018ea1d28c).

Answer (score 1):

The relevant `std::forward` and `std::move` declarations are:

```
template< class T >
T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t );

template< class T >
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move( T&& t );
```

For the former:

```
std::forward<MetaData>(other._metadata);
```

`std::forward<MetaData>` returns `MetaData&&`.

For the latter:

```
 std::move(other._metadata);
 //argument derived as lvalue reference due to forwarding reference
 std::move<MetaData&>(other._name);
```

`std::move<MetaData&>` returns `typename std::remove_reference<MetaData&>::type&&`, which is `MetaData&&`.

So the two forms are identical for your example. However, `std::move` is the right choice here, as it shows our intent to unconditionally move the argument. `std::forward` *can* be used to unconditionally move, but the purpose of it is to perfect-forward its argument.