# Calling function based on the value categories of its arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

Yesterday I asked [a question about when to use `std::forward` and when to use `std::move`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349944/move-and-forward-cases-use)

Today I was trying to apply what I think I learned. I wrote the following:

```
template <typename T>
void exp(T a, T b)
{
  cout << "rvalues" << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void exp(T& a, T& b)
{
  cout << "lvalues" << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T&& a, T&& b)
{
  exp(forward<T>(a), forward<T>(b));
}
```

When in the `main` I call `foo(4, 5)` it prints out `"rvalue"`, as I would expect, but when I do something like

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
foo(a, b);
```

an error occurs that says: `'exp' : ambiguous call to overloaded function`

What am I missing here? Why the last call to `foo(a, b)` doesn't call the `void exp(T& a, T& b)` function?

Comment: What function would you pick?

Comment: In my mind, when I call `foo(a, b)` I think the program should pick the `void exp(T& a, T& b)` function. Anyway, I edited the description with a further question, thank you!

Comment: Why not `void exp(T, T)`?

Comment: Cause `a` and `b` are lvalue reference and `forward` will preserve the lvalue reference for `exp`...

Comment: And I know that I can't use `T&&` in a templated function cause it doesn't mean `rvalue reference`

Comment: None of the overloads is more specialized than another one, and both are viable for lvalue arguments

Comment: Ok. When should I use forward then?

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that `void exp(T a, T b)` accepts only rvalues. It accepts *everything*.

Comment: is there a way to make sure that a function accepts only rvalues?

Comment: @Agostino http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afca0e6573dd0686

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That SFINAE is totally not needed in this case. Partial ordering FTW.

Comment: BTW, example may be simplified to 1 argument and to `exp(a)` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both reference binding and an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion are given an exact match rank:

§ 13.3.3.1.4 [over.ics.ref]/p1:

> When a parameter of reference type binds directly (8.5.3) to an argument expression, the implicit conversion sequence is the **identity conversion.**

Thus, the compiler can't choose between the two on the basis of better conversion sequence selection, and tries to partially order the two overloads of `exp` (because the more specialized function templates take precedence in overload resolution). However:

§ 14.8.2.4 [temp.deduct.partial]/p5:

> Before the partial ordering is done, certain transformations are performed on the types used for partial ordering:
>
> — If `P` is a reference type, `P` is replaced by the type referred to.
>
> — If `A` is a reference type, `A` is replaced by the type referred to.

This makes the two overloads indistinguishable, since neither is more specialized, as from the partial ordering point of view they look the same, and no other exception applies.

If your primary goal is to have one overload for rvalues and another for lvalues, you can define them as follows:

```
template <typename T>
void exp(T&& a, T&& b) {}

template <typename T>
void exp(T& a, T& b) {}
```

Now, although `exp(T&& a, T&& b)` is viable for lvalues as well, the other overload is deemed *more specialized*:

§ 14.8.2.4 [temp.deduct.partial]/p9:

> If, for a given type, deduction succeeds in both directions (i.e., the types are identical after the transformations above) and **both `P` and `A` were reference types** (before being replaced with the type referred to above):
>
> — if the type from the argument template was an lvalue reference and the type from the parameter
>   template was not, the argument type is considered to be more specialized than the other; otherwise [...]

which makes `exp(T& a, T& b)` to be the preffered one for lvalues, and `exp(T&& a, T&& b)` the only viable for rvalues in turn.

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/831fb03df4313e15)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but at this point, if I delete the forward part from the `foo` function, the only function called will be the lvalue specialized one. Am I right?

Comment: I understood it. I asked this just for curiosity

Comment: @Agostino Yes, without `std::forward` the value category of arguments passed to `exp` is lvalue

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the explaination, it really helped me

Comment: Anyway I didn't use the `T&&` in the `exp` function at first because I knew it was a universal reference, therefore not specialized.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of exp which prints rvalues is incorrect.
It should be:

```
template <typename T>
void exp(T&& a, T&& b)
{
  cout << "rvalues" << endl;
}
```

If you call foo(a, b) the compiler could have chosen to copy a and b and call your rvalues version when in fact they are not rvalues.
That is why you received the compilation error.

If you really want to see if the argument is an rvalue you can use is_rvalue_reference:

```
template <typename T>
void exp(T&& a, T&& b)
{
  std::cout << "rvalues: " << std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value << std::endl;
}
```

If you want one function for rvalues and one for lvalues then you can use enable_if:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value, void>::type exp(T&& a, T&& b)
{
  std::cout << "rvalues" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_rvalue_reference<T&>::value, void>::type exp(T& a, T& b)
{
  std::cout << "lvalues" << std::endl;
}
```

You might need to include the type_traits header file.

Comment: It should be `(T&& , T&&)` too for the second one.

Comment: or replace the `enable_if` by `void` directly.

Comment: sorry, fixed the answer, should have used T& in the second is_rvalue_reference.