# Is std::forward required to pass rValue parameter to the make_ smart pointer functions?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I've just started looking into move semantics and Rvalue references so I am learning as I go along, I was wondering whether a call to `std::forward` is needed when passing an Rvalue function parameter into a smart pointer?

```cpp
void CreateUniquePtr(int&& value)
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_unique<int>(std::forward<int>(value));
}
```

vs

```cpp
void CreateUniquePtr(int&& value)
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_unique<int>(value);
}
```

Comment: Interesting note: `value` is not an Rvalue, and is, confusingly, an lvalue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486367/why-do-you-use-stdmove-when-you-have-in-c11/14486705#14486705

Comment: There is no reason to use `std::forward` outside of template cases. Using in any non-template case is pointless and possibly wrong.