# A function template using std::forward and rvalue

Tags: c++

Given the following function template from "The C++ Programming language 4th edition":

```
template <typename TT, typename A>
unique_ptr<TT> make_unique(int i, A && a)
{
      return unique_ptr<TT>{new TT{ i, std::forward<A>(a) }};
}
```

I find it difficult to understand what that actually does,

a is definitely an rvalue and therefore the make_unique function 
seem to allocate its content on the heap and holding that address in a unique_ptr so we won't have to worry about deleting it. but, what does the standard library forward function does? (I guess it has something to do with a being rvalue) I tried reading at C++ documentation but I don't seem to understand that properly.
would love to get a good explanation from a more experienced C++ programmer.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... I'm pretty sure this isn't given as a work-around implementation of the future `std::make_unique`, but anyway, what the function does is pretty easy to understand, though it requires you to have prior knowledge of new C++11 features.

```
template <typename TT, typename A>
unique_ptr<TT> make_unique(int i, A && a)
{
      return unique_ptr<TT>{new TT{ i, std::forward<A>(a) }};
}
```

First of all `make_unique` is a *function template*, I really hope you already know that, as the following would *require* that you have at least the most basic knowledge on what templates does and how templates work.

Now to the non-trivial parts. `A && a` there is a function parameter. Specifically, `a` is the function parameter whose type is `A&&` which is an [*r-value reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5481539/1619294). With its type being a template type parameter, we can deduce its type from whatever the caller passes as an argument to `a`. Whenever we have r-value reference and argument type deduction, special deduction rules and reference collapsing kicks-in and we have a so-called *"universal reference"* which is particularly useful for perfect forwarding functions.

Whenever we have a universal reference (`a` in our case), we will almost always want to preserve its original "l-valueness" or "r-valueness" whenever we want to use them. To have this kind of behavior, we should almost always use [`std::forward`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257144/when-to-use-stdforward-to-forward-arguments) (`std::forward<A>(a)`). By using `std::forward`, a variable originally passed as an l-value remains an l-value and a variable originally passed as an r-value remains an r-value.

After that, things are just simple

```
return unique_ptr<TT>{new TT{ i, std::forward<A>(a) }};
```

Notice the use of the braces. Instead of using parentheses, it is using C++11's [*uniform initialization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization) syntax of calling constructors. With `new TT{ i, std::forward<A>(a) }`, you are dynamically allocating an object of type `TT` with the given parameters inside the braces. With `unique_ptr<TT>{new TT{ i, std::forward<A>(a) }};`, you are creating a `unique_ptr<TT>` whose parameter is the one returned by the dynamic allocation. The `unique_ptr<TT>` object now then returned from the function.

Answer (score 1):

Due to template argument deduction and reference collapsing rules you cannot know if `a` is a rvalue reference or a lvalue reference. `std::forward` passes the argument to the TT contrustor exactly as it was passed to make_unique. Scott Meyers calls `A&&` a [universal reference](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers), because it can be a lvalue ref or an rvalue ref, depended on what is passed to make_unique.

If you pass an rvalue `Foo` to `make_unique`, `std::forward` passes an rvalue reference.

If you pass an lvalue `Foo` to `make_unique`, `std::forward` passes an lvalue reference.

```
 make_unique(1, Foo());         // make_unique(int, A&&) -> rvalue ref
 Foo f;
 make_unique(1, f);             // make_unique(int, A&&&) -> make_unique(int, A&) -> lvalue ref
 make_unique(1, std::move(f));  // make_unique(int, A&&&&) -> make_unique(int, A&&) -> rvalue ref
```