# Why should I use std::forward?

Tags: c++, c++11

In the code below, why should I use `std::forward` when passing around arguments?

```
class Test {
  public:
  Test() {
      std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
  }
  Test(const Test&) {
      std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl;
  }
  Test(const Test&&) {
      std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl;
  }
};

template<typename Arg>
void pass(Arg&& arg) {
    // use arg..
    return; 
}

template<typename Arg, typename ...Args>
void pass(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    // use arg...
    return pass(args...); // why should I use std::forward<Arg>(args)... ?
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pass(std::move<Test>(Test()));

    return 0;
}
```

The code with or without `std::forward` doesn't show any copy/move around.

Comment: Related; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257144/when-to-use-stdforward-to-forward-arguments

Comment: 3834459 what about the above two posts leaves you confused?  Or do they answer your problem?

Comment: Test(const Test&&) is NOT a "move ctor". Test(Test&&) is.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a number of good posts on what `std::forward` does and how it works (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257144/when-to-use-stdforward-to-forward-arguments)).

In a nutshell, **it preserves the value category of its argument**. Perfect forwarding is there to ensure that the argument provided to a function is forwarded to another function (or used within the function) with the same value category (basically r-value vs. l-value) as [originally provided](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward). It is typically used with template functions where [reference collapsing](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) may have taken place (involving universal/forwarding references).

Consider the code sample below. Removing the `std::forward` would print out `requires lvalue` and adding the `std::forward` prints out `requires rvalue`. The `func` is overloaded based on whether it is an rvalue or an lvalue. Calling it without the `std::forward` calls the incorrect overload. The `std::forward` is required in this case as `pass` is called with an rvalue.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
class Test {
  public:
  Test() {
      std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
  }
  Test(const Test&) {
      std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl;
  }
  Test(Test&&) {
      std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl;
  }
};

void func(Test const&)
{
    std::cout << "requires lvalue" << std::endl;
}

void func(Test&&)
{
    std::cout << "requires rvalue" << std::endl;
}

template<typename Arg>
void pass(Arg&& arg) {
    // use arg here
    func(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    return; 
}

template<typename Arg, typename ...Args>
void pass(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    // use arg here
    return pass(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    pass(std::move<Test>(Test()));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would it be incorrect to call the Test const& version? I mean: what's the price in that?

Comment: @user3834459 Depends on what the function does. If the functionality between the two overloads requires (or is optimised for) the value category, then yes, else probably not. In general, given the two overloads, one is left to assume that there is some difference and it would be better to call the correct version.