# Aren't forwarding references deduced as r-value references?

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

I have a specific question regarding forwarding references. (I think) I understand r-value references and `std::move`, but I have trouble understanding forwarding references:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T> class TD; // from "Effective Modern C++"

void consume(const int &i) { std::cout << "lvalue\n"; }
void consume(int &&i)      { std::cout << "rvalue\n"; }

template <typename T>
void foo(T&& x) {
//    TD<decltype(x)> xType; - prints int&&
    consume(x);
}

int main() {
    foo(1 + 2);
}
```

`T` is `int`, that's fine. If `x` is of type `int&&`, why it prints "lvalue" and we need `std::forward` ? I mean, where is the conversion from `int&&` to `const int&` here?

Comment: `x` has a name, so it is a lvalue.

Comment: lvalue / rvalue are _categories of expressions_. `decltype` unfortunately mixes expression categories and variable types :(

Comment: You might see the difference with `decltype((x))` versus `decltype(x)` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/446648ba5649164a)

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550603/why-should-i-use-stdforward and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483250/rvalue-reference-is-treated-as-an-lvalue

Comment: The dupe is incorrect. I understand that (any) references can be converted to pointers with the address-of operator. That's not what I ask about. What I ask is why r-value references don't bind to r-value references, but to l-value references.

Comment: Not sure how you think it doesn't answer the question.  The second sentence in the accepted answer is *Whatever has a name is an lvalue*, which explains why the rvalue reference is being treated as an lvalue.

Comment: My question is entirely different. I do not ask about the body of the `consume(int &&i)` function. While the answer you cited provides some insight, it doesn't explain the difference between types and value categories which seems to be the key here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Types and [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue) are two independent properties of expression.

> Each C++ [expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions) (an operator with its operands, a literal, a variable name, etc.) is characterized by two independent properties: a *type* and a *value category*. Each expression has some non-reference type, and each expression belongs to exactly one of the three primary value categories: *prvalue*, *xvalue*, and *lvalue*.

The type of `x` is `int&&`, but `x` is the name of variable and `x` is an lvalue expression itself, which just can't be bound to `int&&` (but could be bound to `const int&`).

(emphasis mine)

> The following expressions are *lvalue expressions*:
>
> - **the name of a variable**, a function`, a template parameter object (since C++20)`, or a data member, regardless of type, such as `std::cin` or `std::endl`. **Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression**;

That means when function has both lvalue-reference and [rvalue-reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Rvalue_references) overloads, value categories are considered in [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Viable_functions) too.

> More importantly, when a function has both rvalue reference and lvalue reference [overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), the rvalue reference overload binds to rvalues (including both prvalues and xvalues), while the lvalue reference overload binds to lvalues:

> If any parameter has reference type, reference binding is accounted for at this step: if an rvalue argument corresponds to non-const lvalue reference parameter or an lvalue argument corresponds to rvalue reference parameter, the function is not viable.

`std::forward` is used for the conversion to rvalue or lvalue, consistent with the original value category of forwarding reference argument. When lvalue `int` is passed to `foo`, `T` is deduced as `int&`, then `std::forward<T>(x)` will be an lvalue expression; when rvalue `int` is passed to `foo`, `T` is deduced as `int`, then `std::forward<T>(x)` will be an rvalue expression. So `std::forward` could be used to reserve the value category of the original forwarding reference argument. As a contrast `std::move` always converts parameter to rvalue expression.

Comment: Thanks! So the function parameter `x` has the _type_ of r-value reference, but any _use_ of `x` is an l-value expression because `x` is a function parameter? Which cannot initialize an r-value reference? This means types and value categories _aren't_ independent things. It is the value category of the argument to `consume` that affects selection of the overload, i.e. function with the correct parameter type.

Can it be explained without understanding the five value categories and the long lists of rules about which expression is of which category?

Comment: @0xF: I've memorized this as: "parameters of type `T&&` can be _constructed_ from an rvalue. But all named variables, including `T&&` variables, are then lvalues.

Comment: *"Types and value categories are two independent things."* I think this breaks when references come into play. E.g. `int& foo();` then the type determines that `foo()` is an lvalue :(

Comment: @0xF I tried to add some more explanations.

Comment: Great answer! If someone reading this feels lost like I was yesterday, I recommend "50 shades of C++" on YouTube. I've just watched it now, only this time it was more scary and less funny than when I watched it back in 2019.

Answer (score 4):

The call `consume(x)` will always select the *`const` lvalue reference overload* of `consume()` because the expression `x` is an *lvalue*. This is regardless of the deduced type for `x`.

However, by calling `consume()` instead as:

```
consume(std::forward<T>(x));
```

It will select the *rvalue reference overload* if the value category of the argument passed to `foo()` (i.e., the wrapper function template with forwarding references) was an *rvalue*.

---

Roughly speaking, `std::forward` propagates or preserves the original *value category* of `foo()`'s argument to the argument of the nested call `consume()`:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& x) {
   // preserve original value category of foo()'s argument
   consume(std::forward<T>(x));
}
```

That is, if `foo()` is passed an rvalue, e.g.:

```
foo(1); // selects consume(int &&)
```

This argument's value category – `1`, an rvalue  – is further propagated through `std::forward` to the call to `consume()`, and therefore the rvalue reference overload (i.e., `void consume(int &&)`) is selected. If `foo()` is passed an lvalue instead, e.g.:

```
foo(i); // selects consume(const int&)
```

Since `i` is an lvalue, and `std::forward` preserves the original value category of this argument to the call to `consume()`, the lvalue reference overload is selected – i.e., `void consume(const int&)`.