# Can we just have one function with variadic templates?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I am taking the code from the solution to one of the old question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550603/why-should-i-use-stdforward)

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
class Test {
  public:
  Test() {
      std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
  }
  Test(const Test&) {
      std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl;
  }
  Test(Test&&) {
      std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl;
  }
};

void func(Test const&)
{
    std::cout << "requires lvalue" << std::endl;
}

void func(Test&&)
{
    std::cout << "requires rvalue" << std::endl;
}

template<typename Arg>
void pass(Arg&& arg) {
    // use arg here
    func(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    return; 
}

template<typename Arg, typename ...Args>
void pass(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    // use arg here
    return pass(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    pass(std::move<Test>(Test()));
    return 0;
}
```

I am wondering if there exists a way to avoid having 2 overloads of the function called `pass` above something like `void pass(Arg&& ...arg)` and still achieve the same functionality as above?

It confuses me to understand when do I need to overloads like taken in above code.

Comment: note that this code is rather old-fashioned. It uses recursion (which isnt needed nowadays) and as always with recursion you need to stop somewhere

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number : exactly that's where I am getting confused and thought if there is rewrite possible now a days to make it simple.

Comment: It is bad usage of `std::move` in `pass(std::move<Test>(Test()));`, `std::move` deduce it argument so `<Test>` should be removed; `Test()` is already a r-value, so `std::move` is unneeded.

Answer (score 4):

In C++17, your might use [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void pass(Ts&&... args)
{
    [[maybe_unused]] auto f = [](auto&& arg){ /* use arg here */};
    (f(std::forward<Ts>(args)), ...);
    func((std::forward<Ts>(args), ...)); // call func only on last parameter
                                      // (assuming no evil overload of operator,)
}
```

Comment: You're missing the final call of the global `func` on the last element of `args`.

Comment: @Holt: Not sure if it is not a typo of OP, else `func((std::forward<Ts>(args), ...));` should do the trick. Added anyway.

Comment: Nice trick You probably don't want to `std::forward` on `args` when calling `f` then.

Comment: @Jarod42 : Can you explain a bit the magic you did? Won't (f(std::forward<Ts>(args)), ...); expand "all" args including the last one? And how will func((std::forward<Ts>(args), ...)); be called only on the last arg? I think you are doing multiple things here.

Comment: @Test: Trick is to use comma operator `(a, ..,  z)` would evaluate `a`, .., `z` (AND return `z`) (assuming no evil overload comma operator). so `(f(args), ...)` is `(f(a), .., f(z))`; on the other side `f((args, ...))` is `f((a, .., z))` and so `f(z)`.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked but... observe that (also before C++17) instead of a template ground-case recursion function that receive an `arg` and duplicate the single `arg` management

```
template <typename Arg>
void pass (Arg && arg) {
    func(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
}
```

you can simply write a non-template empty (no `arg` received, no `arg` managed) `pass()` function

```
void pass ()
{ }
```