# std::move or std::forward with parameter std::unique_ptr<T>&&

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following template class (stripped down to contain only the relevant parts) with a method called `Push` written in C++ 11:

```
template<class T, int Capacity>
class CircularStack
{
private:
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<T>, Capacity> _stack;

public:
   void Push(std::unique_ptr<T>&& value)
   {
      //some code omitted that updates an _index member variable

      _stack[_index] = std::move(value);
   }
}
```

My question is:

> Should I be using `std::move` or `std::forward` within `Push`?

I am not sure whether `std::unique_ptr<T>&&` qualifies as a universal reference and therefore should be using `forward` rather than `move`.

I am reasonably new to C++.

Comment: If you are comming from a manged language, try not to imitate a "reference to-" approach. In C++, array of object should be in most cases an array of object, not an array of references which is populated dynamically with `new`. keep that in mind.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9671749, http://stackoverflow.com/q/7257144.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, would `std::unique_ptr<T>` be OK  given `Push` will be given instances of types that inherit `T`?

Comment: @keith Yes, `std::unique_ptr` is reasonable for containers which own polymorphic types, like the situation you describe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `std::move`.

`std::unique_ptr<T>&&` is an rvalue reference, not a forwarding reference*. Forwarding references in function parameters must look like `T&&` where `T` is deduced, i.e. a template parameter of the function being declared.

* *forwarding reference* is the preferred name for what you call a universal reference.