# Comparison between usage of std::forward

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the simple code (Disclaimer: This is a noobie question) :

```
template<typename T> struct foo
{
foo(const T&);
foo(T&& ctorArguement):ptrToSomeType(new someType(std::forward<T&&>(ctorArguement))){}
                                                                ^^
std::unique_ptr<someType> ptrToSomeType;
}
```

compared to this :

```
template<typename T> struct foo
{
foo(const T&);
foo(T&& ctorArguement):ptrToSomeType(new someType(std::forward<T>(ctorArguement))){}
                                                               ^^
std::unique_ptr<someType> ptrToSomeType;
}
```

I think I should have used std::move but I was wondering particularly about these two cases. So are two version completely equal, or one is better than another?.

Comment: None of them are at all appropriate. You want `forward<T>` when the parameter is a deduced `T&&`, and you want `move` when the parameter binds an rvalue.

Comment: @KerrekSB But will those above code work, considering the constructor is rvalue? Thanks

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [When to use std::forward to forward arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257144/when-to-use-stdforward-to-forward-arguments)

Comment: It must be embarrassing for you all C++ pros to answer such question? :p :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those two code snippets do the same thing. The first one casts to `T&& &&`, which is `T&&`. The second one casts to `T&&`. Using `std::move` would have the same effect.

To avoid confusing readers of the code (this includes yourself), you should use `std::move` in this context. `std::forward<T>` is only supposed to be used when the `T` is deduced from a forwarding reference `T&&`, and that's not the case in your code since the `T` is actually a parameter for the enclosing *class*, not the function. As for `std::forward<T&&>`, it does the same thing as `std::forward<T>` when the latter is applicable, but this is not at all obvious, so it will also confuse readers.

Comment: *"Using std::move would have the same effect."*, not necessarily true if (for some reason) `T` is an lvalue reference type, then `std::forward<T>` is more appropriate

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki If `T` is an lvalue reference type, the whole class is ill-formed since both overloads would reduce to taking the same argument. So whole thing is moot.

Comment: @Barry "both overloads would reduce to taking the same argument" how is that? pleaseeee explain ? Thanks