# Using sprintf with std::string in C++

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I am using `sprintf` function in C++ 11, in the following way:

```
std::string toString()
{
    std::string output;
    uint32_t strSize=512;
    do
    {
        output.reserve(strSize);
        int ret = sprintf(output.c_str(), "Type=%u Version=%u ContentType=%u contentFormatVersion=%u magic=%04x Seg=%u",
            INDEX_RECORD_TYPE_SERIALIZATION_HEADER,
            FORAMT_VERSION,
            contentType,
            contentFormatVersion,
            magic,
            segmentId);

        strSize *= 2;
    } while (ret < 0);

    return output;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, than to check every time if the reserved space was enough? For future possibility of adding more things.

Comment: Are you using `snprintf`? Because `sprintf`, as shown in your code, has no way to determine the buffer size. `snprintf` would also return the required buffer size, so you could just use the returned value +1 as new `strSize`.

Comment: This code is very wrong. `reserve` does not change the size of the string, and `sprintf` does not return negative just because you wrote out of bounds . You need to allocate the space you need *before* writing out of bounds.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your construct -- *writing* into the buffer received from `c_str()` -- is **undefined behaviour**, even if you checked the string's capacity beforehand. (The return value is a pointer to **const** char, and the function itself marked **const**, for a reason.)

Don't mix C and C++, *especially* not for writing into internal object representation. (That is breaking very basic OOP.) Use C++, for type safety and not running into conversion specifier / parameter mismatches, if for nothing else.

```
std::ostringstream s;
s << "Type=" << INDEX_RECORD_TYPE_SERIALIZATION_HEADER
  << " Version=" << FORMAT_VERSION
  // ...and so on...
  ;
std::string output = s.str();
```

Alternative:

```
std::string output = "Type=" + std::to_string( INDEX_RECORD_TYPE_SERIALIZATION_HEADER )
                   + " Version=" + std::to_string( FORMAT_VERSION )
                   // ...and so on...
                   ;
```

Comment: how can i simulate the string formatting in ostringstream, like magic=%04x and so on?

Comment: @danieltheman: [`setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw), [`setfill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill).

Comment: Your comment *'The return value is a pointer to **const** char, and the function itself marked **const**, for a reason'* implies that the code presented *should not even compile* due to `const` qualifier mismatch at `sprintf(output.c_str(), ...` expression. So it's false OP *is using* `sprintf` the way he described, because a presented excerpt is not a runnable code...

Comment: @CiaPan it doesn't technically imply that the code should not even compile. If we assume the knowledge that implicit conversion from const to non-const is ill-formed, then it implies that a compiler is not *required* to compile the code, but the compiler can support the conversion as a non-standard language extension. The compiler is simply required to give the user a diagnostic message, if the program is ill-formed according to the standard. *If* it does compile, then the write through the const pointer is UB.

Comment: @user2079303 Got it. Thank you for the explanation, I thought compilers are not allowed to accept such code.

Comment: @CiaPan: Quite generally speaking, a compiler's warnings and a language's rules are only losely coupled. This is doubly true for C/C++, which made it a credo that "the developer knows what he's doing".

Answer (score 17):

The C++ patterns shown in other answers are nicer, but for completeness, here is a correct way with `sprintf`:

```
auto format = "your %x format %d string %s";
auto size = std::snprintf(nullptr, 0, format /* Arguments go here*/);
std::string output(size + 1, '\0');
std::sprintf(&output[0], format, /* Arguments go here*/);
```

Pay attention to

- You must `resize` your string. `reserve` does not change the size of the buffer. In my example, I construct correctly sized string directly.
- `c_str()` returns a `const char*`. You may not pass it to `sprintf`.
- `std::string` buffer was not guaranteed to be contiguous prior to C++11 and this relies on that guarantee. If you need to support exotic pre-C++11 conforming platforms that use rope implementation for `std::string`, then you're probably better off *sprinting* into `std::vector<char>` first and then copying the vector to the string.
- This only works if the arguments are not modified between the size calculation and formatting; use either local copies of variables or thread synchronisation primitives for multi-threaded code.

Comment: Interesting; I am not quite sure if the construct (writing to `&output[0]`) is adhering to the letter of the standard, though. This will probably work for next to all implementations of `std::string`, but as for well-definedness, I have doubts.

Comment: @DevSolar If I remember correctly, contiguousness of `std::string` buffer is guaranteed since c++11. Prior to that, it was not guaranteed. As far as I know, there are no other reasons for this to not work.

Comment: @user2079303 string constructor that gets a number in it? i don`t think there is such thing in c++, can you please elaborate? i am talking about this: 
std::string output(size + 1);

Comment: @danieltheman sorry, I meant to use the constructor that takes a size, and a `char`. I forgot that the second argument has no default value. The code is now fixed.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use `std::snprintf(&output[0], size, format, /* args go here */);` instead of the last line to be safer? Imagine that another thread modifies one of the format string args (say, an integer goes from 9 to 10, thereby taking up one more character) between the `auto size = ...` assignment and the `std::sprintf()` call at the end.

Comment: @ThomasPerl The size calculation, buffer allocation, and the output operation really only make sense in a non-data-race context. That's a good point. The size accepting version of `sprintf` would indeed avoid UB in a data race, but you would still have the possibility of arbitrarily cut-off output. You really should use a critical section to avoid a race here - and if you do, then the non-size and size using versions are equally safe. Or alternatively, simply use local copies of the non-const arguments so that they cannot be modified by other threads.

Comment: Many code analysis tools will warn about sprintf(), so makes sense to always use snprintf().

Comment: It's good. The string should be resized again at the end of the code snippet to snip off the terminating null.

Comment: Why not `std::string output(size, '\0');`, without the +1? That [constructor (4)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) copies N times the character AND adds a terminating `\0`, effectively having `size+1` bytes. If you pass in `size+1`, it ends up having `size+2` bytes, with the last "real" char set to `\0`, which will cause problems when concatenating, size computing and so

Answer (score 6):

We can mix code from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36909699/2667451 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7257307 and result will be like that:

```
template <typename ...Args>
std::string stringWithFormat(const std::string& format, Args && ...args)
{
    auto size = std::snprintf(nullptr, 0, format.c_str(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    std::string output(size + 1, '\0');
    std::sprintf(&output[0], format.c_str(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should add 1 to the string size for the null terminator. `std::string` doesn't require it. It should be rather `std::string output(size, '\0');` instead.

Answer (score 2):

A better way is to use the [{fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt). Ex:

```
std::string message = fmt::sprintf("The answer is %d", 42);
```

It exposes also a nicer interface than iostreams and printf. Ex:

```
std::string message = fmt::format("The answer is {}", 42);`
```

See:
https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt
http://fmtlib.net/latest/api.html#printf-formatting-functions

Comment: 3rd party lib...?

Comment: @hfrmobile Not anymore. Now part of the C++20 standard: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong. `reserve` allocates memory for the string, but does not change its size. Writing into the buffer returned by `c_str` does not change its size either. So the string still believes its size is 0, and you've just written something into the unused space in the string's buffer. (Probably. Technically, the code has Undefined Behaviour, because writing into `c_str` is undefined, so anything could happen).

What you really want to do is forget `sprintf` and similar C-style functions, and use the C++ way of string formatting—string streams:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << "Type=" << INDEX_RECORD_TYPE_SERIALIZATION_HEADER
   << " Version=" << FORAMT_VERSION
   << /* ... the rest ... */;
return ss.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is!

In C, the better way is to associate a file with the *null* device and make a dummy `printf` of the desired output to it, to learn how much space would it take if actually printed. Then allocate appropriate buffer and `sprintf` the same data to it.

In C++ you could associate the output stream with a null device, too, and test the number of charactes printed with [std::ostream::tellp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/tellp/). However, using `ostringstream` is a way better solution – see the answers by DevSolar or Angew.

Comment: Completely missing the point that you cannot write to the buffer returned by `c_str()`, and needlessly complicated even then since there is `snprintf()` / `snprintf_s`.

Comment: `snprintf` is better than the null device hack. But you have to use that hack for `swprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an implementation of `sprintf()` into a `std::string` I wrote that uses `vsnprintf()` under the hood.

It splits the format string into sections of plain text which are just copied to the destination `std::string` and sections of format fields (such as `%5.2lf`) which are first `vsnprintf()`ed into a buffer and then appended to the destination.

https://gitlab.com/eltomito/bodacious-sprintf